# How can I report an app that contains ads but didn't provide a privacy policy url to Apple?

Tags: privacy

How can I report an app that contains ads but didn't provide a privacy policy url to Apple?
I have tried to google myself, but I couldn't find a way to report it.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202140/privacy-policy-url-for-app?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app that doesn't have a privacy policy isn't necessary breaking any of Apple's rules or guidelines. The requirement that all these apps must have a privacy policy is quite new, and only apps or app updates submitted to the App Store after October 3rd 2018 need to comply.

You can use the following link to contact Apple's customer service:

https://getsupport.apple.com/

Choose "Apps and Software" and then "App Store".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found that the app was updated before October 3rd, and it will be updated and provide a valid privacy policy url after the Christmas vacation. I should have contacted Apple support directly if I encounter similar issue again. So thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You find a list of all ways Apple can be contacted on the [Contacting Apple](https://www.apple.com/contact/) page which is linked on the bottom of https://www.apple.com/.

Comment: If the OP can’t find those links....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I should have just contacted the Apple support directly.. I actually found several links to the Apple support but they all looked different, so I wasn't sure where to go. However, any of these links should be working. So thanks for the answer.